# XML - Extract One tag Value

Tags: java, xml

I have to extract tag value from an xml Document that contains a single tag like below:

```
<error>Permission denied</error>
```

i have tried:

```
String xmlRecords = "<error>Permission denied</error>"
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlRecords));
Document doc = db.parse(is);
Node nodes = doc.getFirstChild();
String = nodes.getNodeValue();
```

but it dont works.
How can i do it ?

Comment: Have you tried XPath?

Comment: You can use DOM parser for future references: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm

Comment: I find this question unclear. Are you looking to extract the string `Permission denied`, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Use `doc.getDocumentElement().getTextContent()` to get the string `Permission denied`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to construct the string if you are using the above approach. You will get the string values of the tag name and content using the functions.

```
Tag name = nodes.getTextContent()

tag value = nodes.getLocalName()
```

Answer (score 0):

With DOM it´s util to know the structure of the XML document, and which node level are you looking for.

After get Document, you can use document.getElementsByTagName("root") to look for the root or father tags, and get the childs as a list to look for the item. Something like this:

```
        NodeList listresults = document.getElementsByTagName('father/root element string');         

        NodeList nl = listresults.item(0).getChildNodes();          

        // Recorremos los nodos
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nl.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node node = nl.item(temp);
            // Check if it is a node
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element element = (Element) node;

                if(element.getNodeName().equals("error")){
                    // check the element
                }                                                                           
            }
        }
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

just try following code.

```
 String value =  nodes.getTextContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want

```
Element element = document.getDocumentElement();    
NodeList errorTagList = element.getElementsByTagName("error");
if (errorTagList != null && errorTagList.getLength() > 0) {
   NodeList errorTagSubList = errorTagList.item(0).getChildNodes();

   if (errorTagSubList != null && errorTagSubList.getLength() > 0) {
     String value = errorTagSubList.item(0).getNodeValue();
   }

}
```